# IOS 9 Safari blocking http get on iframes

Tags: html, ios, iframe

We are having a trouble in our website which only happens in IOS9 and only when an iframe is involved.

Our website is used by external applications as a gateway, and they include our content in their sites. Those external apps that include our content within an iframe are experimenting troubles when they access the site from ios9 safari browser.

The thing is that we have some HTTP/GET calls in our web to get some images from a servlet and those calls, are blocked on IOS9, but only for those sites that include our page in iframes...

Both for sites which do not use iframe and for previous IOS versions work, only the combination of IOS9 + iframe is causing that issue.

Is there anything related to this IOS version that can cause this? Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance.